# Merging Two XML CTE's In SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need some help merging two XML CTE's together in SQL Server. I've worked with CTE's before, but it seems more complex when XML is involved. I appreciate any suggestions.

I've tried to cross apply the two XML CTE's together based on common key, `refid`, but haven't had any success.

```sql
;With TBL1_Fruits As 
(Select '1' as refid,
        'Apples' as fruits,
        'Red' as color,
        'Macintosh' as  category union
 Select  '2' as refid,
        'Oranges' as fruits,
        'Orange' as color,
        'Bergamot' as category union
 Select '3' as refid,
        'Bananas' as fruits,
        'Yellow' as color,
        'Cavendish' as category)

,TBL1_Export As
(Select 'X1234' as ShipID,
        'USA' as Country,
        'FarmersToYou' as Brand,
        '1' as refid union
 Select 'Y1234' as ShipID,
        'Costa_Rica' as Country,
        'Chiquita' as Brand,
        '3' as refid union
 Select 'Z1234' as ShipID,
        'USA' as Country,
        'Hawaiia_Sun_Tropical' as Brand,
        '2' as refid)

,TBL2_Price As
(Select '1' as refid,
        '4.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit union
 Select '2' as refid,
        '6.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit union
 Select '3' as refid,
        '2.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit)
,TBL2_Costs As
(Select '1' as refid,
        '1.50' as shipping_cost,
        '3.00' as profit,
        'lb' as unit_rev union
 Select '2' as refid,
        '3.00' as shipping_cost,
    '3.50' as profit,
    'lb' as unit_rev union
 Select '3' as refid,
        '0.50' as shipping_cost,
    '2.00' as profit,
    'lb' as unit_rev)

,XML1 As (Select * From (
Select refid, fruits, color, category,
 (Select Distinct ShipID, Country, Brand from TBL1_Export
   Where TBL1_Export.refid = TBL1_Fruits.refid
   FOR XML PATH ('FruitAttributes'),TYPE)
  From (Select Distinct refid, fruits, color, category From TBL1_Fruits) 
  TBL1_Fruits
  FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('FruitInfo'), TYPE) As x(Fruits))

,XML2 As 
(Select * From (
Select refid, price, unit,
 (Select Distinct shipping_cost, profit, unit_rev from TBL2_Costs
   Where TBL2_Price.refid = TBL2_Costs.refid
   FOR XML PATH ('FruitProfit'),TYPE)
  From (Select Distinct refid, price, unit From TBL2_Price) TBL2_Price
  FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('FruitRevenue'), TYPE) As c(Fruits))
```

How do I combine XML1 and XML2 to produce the following:

Basically what I'm looking for is after XML1, XML2 continues but is matched by `refid` from XML2 to XML1. How can I write this query?

```xml
<FruitInfo>
  <refid>1</refid>
  <fruits>Apples</fruits>
  <color>Red</color>
  <category>Macintosh</category>
  <FruitAttributes>
    <ShipID>X1234</ShipID>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Brand>FarmersToYou</Brand>
  </FruitAttributes>
</FruitInfo>
<FruitRevenue>
  <refid>1</refid>
  <price>4.50</price>
  <unit>lb</unit>
  <FruitProfit>
    <shipping_cost>1.50</shipping_cost>
    <profit>3.00</profit>
    <unit_rev>lb</unit_rev>
  </FruitProfit>
</FruitRevenue>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've put this t complicated... Try this:

Assuming your CTEs are simulations of tables I changed this for readability:

```
DECLARE @TBL1_Fruits TABLE(refid INT,fruits VARCHAR(100),color VARCHAR(100),category VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TBL1_Fruits(refid,fruits,color,category) 
(Select '1' as refid,
        'Apples' as fruits,
        'Red' as color,
        'Macintosh' as  category union
 Select  '2' as refid,
        'Oranges' as fruits,
        'Orange' as color,
        'Bergamot' as category union
 Select '3' as refid,
        'Bananas' as fruits,
        'Yellow' as color,
        'Cavendish' as category);

DECLARE @TBL1_Export TABLE(ShipID VARCHAR(100),Country VARCHAR(100),Brand VARCHAR(100),refid INT);
INSERT INTO @TBL1_Export(ShipID,Country,Brand,refid)
(Select 'X1234' as ShipID,
        'USA' as Country,
        'FarmersToYou' as Brand,
        '1' as refid union
 Select 'Y1234' as ShipID,
        'Costa_Rica' as Country,
        'Chiquita' as Brand,
        '3' as refid union
 Select 'Z1234' as ShipID,
        'USA' as Country,
        'Hawaiia_Sun_Tropical' as Brand,
        '2' as refid);

DECLARE @TBL2_Price TABLE(refid INT,price DECIMAL(10,4),unit VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TBL2_Price(refid,price,unit)
(Select '1' as refid,
        '4.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit union
 Select '2' as refid,
        '6.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit union
 Select '3' as refid,
        '2.50' as price,
        'lb' as unit);

DECLARE @TBL2_Costs TABLE(refid INT,shipping_cost DECIMAL(10,4),profit DECIMAL(10,4),unit_rev VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TBL2_Costs(refid,shipping_cost,profit,unit_rev)
(Select '1' as refid,
        '1.50' as shipping_cost,
        '3.00' as profit,
        'lb' as unit_rev union
 Select '2' as refid,
        '3.00' as shipping_cost,
    '3.50' as profit,
    'lb' as unit_rev union
 Select '3' as refid,
        '0.50' as shipping_cost,
    '2.00' as profit,
    'lb' as unit_rev);
```

--If I get this correctly, you can do this with nested paths rather than with sub-queries:

```
SELECT e.refid AS [FruitInfo/refid]
      ,f.fruits AS [FruitInfo/fruits]
      ,f.color AS [FruitInfo/color]
      ,f.category AS [FruitInfo/category]
      ,e.ShipID AS [FruitInfo/FruitAttributes/ShipID]
      ,e.Country AS [FruitInfo/FruitAttributes/Country]
      ,e.Brand AS [FruitInfo/FruitAttributes/Brand]
      ,e.refid AS [FruitRevenue/refid]
      ,p.price AS [FruitRevenue/price]
      ,p.unit AS [FruitRevenue/unit]
      ,c.shipping_cost AS [FruitRevenue/FruitProfit/shipping_unit]
      ,c.profit AS [FruitRevenue/FruitProfit/profit]
      ,c.unit_rev AS [FruitRevenue/FruitProfit/unit_rev]
FROM @TBL1_Export e
INNER JOIN @TBL1_Fruits f ON e.refid=f.refid
INNER JOIN @TBL2_Costs c ON e.refid=c.refid
INNER JOIN @TBL2_Price p ON e.refid=p.refid
WHERE e.refid=1 --<-- Remove this to get all at once
FOR XML PATH('')
--Or use this to get your XML in appropritate nestings
--FOR XML PATH('Fruit'),ROOT('Fruits')
```

The result (part of it)

```
<FruitInfo>
  <refid>1</refid>
  <fruits>Apples</fruits>
  <color>Red</color>
  <category>Macintosh</category>
  <FruitAttributes>
    <ShipID>X1234</ShipID>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Brand>FarmersToYou</Brand>
  </FruitAttributes>
</FruitInfo>
<FruitRevenue>
  <refid>1</refid>
  <price>4.5000</price>
  <unit>lb</unit>
  <FruitProfit>
    <shipping_unit>1.5000</shipping_unit>
    <profit>3.0000</profit>
    <unit_rev>lb</unit_rev>
  </FruitProfit>
</FruitRevenue>
```

But your issue has a lot of open questions:

Is `refid` the best column to link between your tables? A fruit won't have the same price in any case, neither the same shipping... I think you should use the fruits table's id as FK in your export table, but the ShipID as FK in your price table (same with costs). This would allow for different prices and costs for each shiping.

In most cases you'll find a price table with a `valid_to` datetime where a product has got a price, while the price used in a given shipment might differ (due to negotiation).